# How can we launch a process through systemd on method_call on some session dbus

Tags: dbus, systemd

I have one agent service (`org.bluez.map_agent`)

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.bluez.map_agent
Exec=echo "Hello"
SystemdService=bluetooth-map-agent.service
```

Content of `bluetooth-map-agent.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=launch MAP agent.

[Service]
User=app
ExecStart=/usr/bin/map-agent
ExecStop=/usr/bin/killall map-agent
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But when `dbus` call happens my map-agent is not getting launched, what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Make your service to launch by systemd itself when the required bus is created by dbus. This can be achieved using below service file:

```
[Unit] 
Description=launch MAP agent.

[Service]
Type=dbus
User=app
BusName=org.bluez.map_agent
ExecStart=/usr/bin/map-agent
ExecStop=/usr/bin/killall map-agent
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And enable your service file using `systemctl enable xyz.service`

Systemd will wait for bus-name to acquire on dbus, only then service will be activated.

Comment: org.bluez.map_agent should be on session bus(i.e user folder while installation of service file) and as far as i know systemctl enable xyz.service require service file should be part of system-services. Please correct if i am wrong